# How Can I Seamlessly Use A Local Bower Dependency?

Tags: javascript, git, dependencies, local, bower

I am developing a library in tandem with a project. The project has the library as a dependency. Both are on my local machine and I have added the path to the lib's git file to the project's `bower.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "example": "/Users/me/Documents/path/to/example/.git"
}
```

This works fine, but every time I update the lib I have to:

1. Add and commit changed files in lib
2. Update the dependency in bower

How can I streamline this process? Is there a way to have the project always use the lib in its current state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL you are currently using for the dependency is identified by Bower as a local git repository and so Bower uses the [Git file system resolver](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/lib/core/resolvers/GitFsResolver.js). This means that your changes must be committed to the repository for Bower to resolve them (The resolver is checking out changes from the local repository).
You can change the URL to something in the form of: `"example": "/Users/me/Documents/path/to/example/"`. You can use a path to a directory, file or an archive.
This will make Bower use the [file system resolver](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/lib/core/resolvers/FsResolver.js) instead which will simply copy the library files (according to the bower.json inside the folder).

Not sure if you can avoid the step of updating the dependency in Bower.